# OOM Exception while creating newRows and adding to datatable from a small CSV file

Tags: c#, exception, datatable, out-of-memory

The code below logs into a https website, grabs a cookie and then navigates to another page to download a CSV file as a string. The string is then split into an array to be used to create DataRows to be added to a datatable. Everything works fine until the loop in the populateTable method, an Out Of Memory exception is thrown. The CSV file is only 206 KB, contains approximately 500 lines, and the array containing the split CSV string contains 16,206 strings. Watching the resource monitor in Windows 7 I can see the program slowly increase its size in RAM to ~1.2 GB before it crashes.

Unfortunately I cannot share the website URL.

I am not really looking for help to fix the issue but rather would like to know why it is occurring as the CSV file is not that large. Any input?

```
namespace GetSCInfo
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("clientInfo");
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createTable();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        //Starting date for the query. the 2f is required
        string startDate = "01%2f01%2f2005";
        string endDate = today.Month.ToString() + "%" + today.Day.ToString() + "%" + today.Year.ToString();

        //Check the date to make sure 2 digits are used for the month and day. If only one is used then add a 0.
        string[] dateFormat = endDate.Split('%');
        if (dateFormat[0].Length < 2)
            dateFormat[0] = "0" + dateFormat[0];
        if (dateFormat[1].Length < 2)
            dateFormat[1] = "0" + dateFormat[1];
        endDate = dateFormat[0] + "%2f" + dateFormat[1] + "%2f" + dateFormat[2];
        //Values for the form on the website
        using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"eid", ""},
            {"EmailAddress", "example@example.com"},
            {"Password", "myPassword"},
            {"chk_NotificationOnly", "false"},
            {"btn_login", "Login"},
        };
            //Login and get the cookie
            client.UploadValues("https://Website/loginpage", values);

            // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
            // so we could download the protected page
            var val2 = new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"StartDate", startDate},
                {"EndDate", endDate},
                {"ReportFormat", "CSV"},
            };

  string bytes = client.DownloadString("https://website/csvPage?StartDate=" + startDate + "&EndDate=" + endDate + "&ReportFormat=CSV");

            client.Dispose();
            populateTable(bytes);


        }


    }

 private void createTable()
 {
     dt.Columns.Add("Assists ID", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));

     dt.Columns.Add("S/C Name", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("S/C Phone", typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add("S/C Email", typeof(string));
 }

private void populateTable(string data)
 {
     dt.Clear();
     string[] csvValues = data.Split(',');
     data = "";
    for(int i = 19; i < csvValues.Length - 19; i=+19)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = csvValues[i];
        row[1] = csvValues[i + 1];
        row[2] = csvValues[i + 2];
        row[3] = csvValues[i + 14];
        row[4] = csvValues[i + 15];
        row[5] = csvValues[i + 16];
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        //dt.Rows.Add(csvValues[i], csvValues[i+1], csvValues[i+2], csvValues[i+14], csvValues[i+15], csvValues[i+16]);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


 }
}
//Extend the Webclient
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private readonly CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself. In `populateTable`, the `for` loop increment isn't incrementing. You've got `i=+19` instead of `i+=19`. You're just setting `i` to 19 and making a new `DataRow` over and over again.